# DiskPressure crashing the node

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

What does DiskPressure really means and how it can be avoided in kubernetes during container creation?

Seemingly when I creating a new container on a node there is a high chance that it is crashing the whole node because of the pressure...

Comment: Just to follow up on this.I had issue eventually with the INodes, not the space. Having a huge  image takes a lot of them.Unfortunately if you have low number of INodes defined on your disks, than these are running out very quickly.Also if you set up auto deletion of the not used images, because of the slow disk vs lot of small files, creating high performance issue on the nodes.So the solution is to set up high number of INodes if you have lot of small files in the image, and have a fast disk to clean it up. Or change the thresholds to lower value (no idea where i can set them up properly...)

Comment: Just one more suggestion if somebody is interested. I used also multi stage builds , which helps to make the final image small. https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/

Comment: This might help: https://gist.github.com/Dufgui/72debe81068bf3ecd7d8 to cleanup the node from unused docker images

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/#node-conditions) you'll find that `DiskPressure` raises when:

> Available disk space and inodes on either the node’s root filesytem or image filesystem has satisfied an eviction threshold

Learning about the conditions of your nodes whenever these issues occur is somewhat important (how much space/inodes are left, ...) and also learning about the related container images is important. This can be done with some basic system monitoring (see the [Resource Usage Monitoring](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/monitoring/)).

Once you know about the conditions, you should consider to adjust the `--low-diskspace-threshold-mb`, `--image-gc-high-threshold` and `--image-gc-low-threshold` parameters of you [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet/), so that there's always enough space for normal operation, or consider to provision more space for your nodes, depending on the requirements.

Comment: Thank you pagid, I will review it as soon as I can.

Comment: Thank you pagid, I didnt get the to check it. But I will come back to, anyway, thank you.

Comment: @pagid how does one interact with kubelet on google kubernetes engine?

Comment: These kubelet commands are [deprecated](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#deprecation-of-existing-feature-flags-to-reclaim-disk) now, in favor of: `--eviction-hard`, `--eviction-soft` and `--eviction-minimum-reclaim`.