# kubernetes+GKE / status is now: NodeHasDiskPressure

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

Read a bit through here (https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/out-of-resource/) without ending up with a clear understanding; Trying here to gather more infos about what actually happens.

We run 2 n1-standard-2 instances, a 300Go disk is attached

More specifically, a "nodefs.inodesFree" problem seems specified. And this one is quite unclear. It seems to happen during builds (when the image is creating), should we understand that it takes too much space on disk ? What would be the most obvious reason ?

It feels like it is not tied to the CPU/memory requests/limits that can be specified on a node, but still as we've "overcommitted" the limits, can it have any impact regarding this issue ?

Thanks for sharing your experience on this one

Comment: This reads like a possible duplicate of [DiskPressure crashing the node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576661/diskpressure-crashing-the-node/42722519)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you run `df -i` on the affected node please?

Comment: You mean, `kubectl exec -it podname -- df -i` ?

Comment: No. On the node itself, the host machine that reports the DiskPressure. If you are unsure, just execute on all nodes (`kubectl get nodes`)

Comment: ssh'ed into from the cloud console, here's the output https://gist.github.com/bbnnt/5cfd0f185c97a0e486e8db7f550dcf22. I have less than 10 pods… Do you think that could go over those 300Go available ? Can't believe it

Comment: 300gb is the size of filesystem, but there is also a limit on how many files/directories (inodes) can be created. The condition nodefs.inodesFree is flagging a problem with not enough inodes available. But the output you attached (thanks!) contradictions that.
There is something fishy going on, I am not sure what, maybe a kubernetes bug. Perhaps we could have a chat tomorrow? (Drop me an email or convert this conversion into a chat)