# The node was low on resource: [DiskPressure]. but df -h shows 47% usage only

Tags: kubernetes

I have a node in my K8S cluster that I use for monitoring tools.

Pods running here: `Grafana`, `PGAdmin`, `Prometheus`, and `kube-state-metrics`

My problem is that I have a lot of evicted pods

The pods evicted: `kube-state-metrics`, `grafana-core`, `pgadmin`

Then, the pod evicted with reason: `The node was low on resource: [DiskPressure].` : `kube-state-metrics` (90% of evicted pods), `pgadmin` (20% of evicted pods)

When I check any of the pods, I have free space on disk:

```
bash-5.0$ df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                   7.4G      3.3G      3.7G  47% /
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs                   484.2M         0    484.2M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2            7.4G      3.3G      3.7G  47% /dev/termination-log
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme0n1p2            7.4G      3.3G      3.7G  47% /etc/resolv.conf
/dev/nvme0n1p2            7.4G      3.3G      3.7G  47% /etc/hostname
/dev/nvme0n1p2            7.4G      3.3G      3.7G  47% /etc/hosts
/dev/nvme2n1            975.9M      8.8M    951.1M   1% /var/lib/grafana
/dev/nvme0n1p2            7.4G      3.3G      3.7G  47% /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources
tmpfs                   484.2M     12.0K    484.2M   0% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs                   484.2M         0    484.2M   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/kcore
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/keys
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/timer_list
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/sched_debug
tmpfs                   484.2M         0    484.2M   0% /sys/firmware
```

Only one or two pods show another message:

```
The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Container addon-resizer was using 48Ki, which exceeds its request of 0. Container kube-state-metrics was using 44Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.

The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Container pgadmin was using 3432Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.
```

I also have kubelet saying:

```
(combined from similar events): failed to garbage collect required amount of images. Wanted to free 753073356 bytes, but freed 0 bytes
```

I have those pods running on a AWS `t3.micro`

It appears that it is not affecting my services in production.

Why is it happening, and how should I fix this.

EDIT: Here is the result when I do `df -h` in my node

```
admin@ip-172-20-41-112:~$ df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           789M  3.0M  786M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  7.5G  6.3G  804M  89% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

I can see that `/dev/nvme0n1p2`, but how can I see the content ? when I do [ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) in /, I can only see 3GB of data...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently you're about to run out of the available disk space **on your node**. However keep in mind that according to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#node-conditions) `DiskPressure` condition denotes:

> Available disk space and inodes on either the node’s root filesystem
>   or image filesystem has satisfied an eviction threshold

Try to run `df -h` but on your worker `node`, not in a `Pod`. What is the percentage of disk usage ? Additionally you may check **kubelet** logs for more details:

```
journalctl -xeu kubelet.service
```

Also take a look at [this](https://medium.com/faun/kubelet-pod-the-node-was-low-on-resource-diskpressure-384f590892f5) article and [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66961#issuecomment-448135500) comment.

Let me know if it helps.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576661/diskpressure-crashing-the-node) you can find an answer which explains very well the same topic.

#### update:

This line clearly shows that the default treshold is close to being exceeded:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2  7.5G  6.3G  804M  89% /
```

Swith to the root user ( `su -` ) and run:

```
du -hd1 /
```

to see what directories take up most of the disk space.

Comment: added an edit on the comment. I have 89% of disk usage. I added an EDIT at the end of the post, I can't see the 8GB I am supposed to have

Comment: Try to switch first to the `root` user and then run `du -sh /`.