# How to reduce the DiskPressure condition threshold of a node

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I want to reduce the `DiskPressure` limit. After reading [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/) (also on [this GitHub case](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66961)), I understand that because of `nodefs.available<10%` I must have my volume free space more than 10%.

I want to change it to 5% but I don't understand how.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42722519/2153777) and in the [node condition by Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#node-conditions), they mention these flag `--eviction-hard` or `eviction-soft` that might be the solution but where should I changed them?

I am using Kubelet config file on the worker node:

```
root@worker:/# cat /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
authentication:
  anonymous:
    enabled: true
  webhook:
    cacheTTL: 0s
    enabled: true
  x509:
    clientCAFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
authorization:
  mode: AlwaysAllow
  #mode: Webhook
  webhook:
    cacheAuthorizedTTL: 0s
    cacheUnauthorizedTTL: 0s
readOnlyPort: 10255
clusterDNS:
- 10.96.0.10
clusterDomain: cluster.local
cpuManagerReconcilePeriod: 0s
evictionPressureTransitionPeriod: 0s
fileCheckFrequency: 0s
healthzBindAddress: 127.0.0.1
healthzPort: 10248
httpCheckFrequency: 0s
imageMinimumGCAge: 0s
kind: KubeletConfiguration
nodeStatusReportFrequency: 0s
nodeStatusUpdateFrequency: 0s
rotateCertificates: true
runtimeRequestTimeout: 0s
staticPodPath: /etc/kubernetes/manifests
streamingConnectionIdleTimeout: 0s
syncFrequency: 0s
volumeStatsAggPeriod: 0s
```

I don't understand what I should change. Most of these settings are seconds (`0s`).
How can I reduce the threshold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This used to be kubelet command line arg.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/

> `--eviction-hard mapStringString`
> A set of eviction thresholds (e.g. `memory.available<1Gi`) that if met
> would trigger a pod eviction.
>
> DEPRECATED:
> This parameter should be
> set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's `--config` flag.
> See
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/
> for more information.

Now it should be specified thru kubelet config file - you were on the right way :)
Just add required entries to your config.

```
evictionHard:
  nodefs.available: 5%
```

Config schema.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/kubelet/config/v1beta1/types.go#L571